# Width and height of SVG as float number

Tags: html, css, svg

When cropping SVG artwork in Illustrator, the width might become for example 20.121021 px instead of exactly 20.

Is there any know problems that can be caused by float number width/height when using the SVGs in HTML/CSS?. Is there a reason to always save the artwork with width and height as integers?

Comment: Having the height and width exact numbers may help you to size it more accurately, but as far as I know, you wont have any issues with float numbers as the height and width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SVG is a Vector format you can use any width / height you want. It doesn't really matter in which width / height you save your SVG from illustrator, you can simply adjust the size within your css.

Just give your SVG (which is actually a text file starting with an `svg` tag) an id / class

```
<svg class="svg--class">...</svg>

.svg--class { 
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

so to answer your question: no, there is no problem saving the SVG with float px numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The extra digits add bloat to an SVG file with lots of paths and don't add precision to most drawings. There are a number of svg clean up utilities that allow you to round up/down path coordinates.